# Heroku Postgresql throws PG::DiskFull

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-postgres

Heroku Postgresql throws "PG::DiskFull: ERROR:  could not write block 312 of temporary file: No space left on device" exception.

It happened only twice when executing select statement.

What can cause it and how i can fix it?

Is there any way how i can contact Heroku team on this issue (not paid support?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.heroku.com/policy/support

> ### 3. Support Channels
>
> Free technical support is available exclusively through the Heroku Support Site located at help.heroku.com.
>
> #### Web
>
> Registered Heroku users can submit new tickets and view history on previously opened tickets.
>
> #### Email
>
> If you are unable to log in or access your account, you may submit a ticket by sending an e-mail from your Heroku account email address to support@heroku.com.